# Jquery code optimization (method attr () for two different div)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, optimization

I'm a newbie to javascript and jquery and every day I learn new things ...
I'm working on a file and I find myself with this code:

```
            $('#mobileuser span').attr({                    
                'class': 'fa fa-user',
                'style':''
            });

            $('#mobilesearch span').attr({                  
                'class': 'fa fa-search',
                'style':''
            });
```

in my groped to optimize i tried this solution but doesn't work:

```
var fontawesome= {          
    mobileuser: 'fa fa-user',
    mobilesearch: 'fa fa-search'    
}

$('#mobilesearch span, #mobileuser span').attr({                    
                'class': fontawesome[$(this).parent('div').attr('id')],
                'style':''
            });
```

Can you suggest me the best way to optimize this code ?

Thanks a lot and sorry for the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#mobilesearch span, #mobileuser span').each(function() {
    $(this).attr({                
        'class': fontawesome[$(this).parent('div').attr('id')],
        'style':''
    });
});
```

Comment: you don't need .each()

Comment: maybe don't need .each but your code @gladsocc is the only that worked

Answer (score 4):

You can pass a function to `.attr`. The function is called for each element matching the selector, and within the function, `this` is the specific element. It should return the object with the specific attributes.

```
$('#mobilesearch span, #mobileuser span').attr(function() {
    return {                
        'class': fontawesome[$(this).parent('div').attr('id')],
        'style':''
    };
});
```

Comment: I try and let you know :)

Comment: I'll suggest replacing the `#id-selector span` with just a `.class-selector`, which will be added to the element that will hold the icon (in this case the `span` tag).

Comment: @Barmar but your code add "return" to both span ? true?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: sorry for me is difficult because i'm italian... i want to add the code in the return to "#mobilesearch span" and to "#mobileuser span", your code not have each() for example... so i ask you if the "return code" is run first for "#mobilesearch span" and also for "#mobileuser span" ....

Comment: You don't need `.each`. `.attr` automatically loops, calls the function for each element, and uses what it returns as the attributes.

Comment: ahhh ok now i understand... i'm sure that your code is good infact now i checked your answer, but my code doesn't work because id a bit different :( can i edit the question ? :(

Comment: Apparently `.attr` only allows a function when you use the two-argument form, to set a single attribute, it doesn't allow a function that returns multiple attributes.